# Gremlin DSE Graph find path on edge/vertex with multiple properties

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, dse

i have a case that maybe anyone in here can help me to figure out gremlin query in DSE Graph to find path on edge/vertex with multiple properties.

[case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7yN6.png)

this is my codes in DSE Graph

```
schema.propertyKey("id").Uuid().ifNotExists().create()`
schema.propertyKey("name").Text().single().create()  
schema.propertyKey("vlan").Text().multiple().create()  
schema.vertexLabel("site").partitionKey('id').properties("id", "name", "vlan").ifNotExists().create()
schema.edgeLabel("linkTo").multiple().properties("id", "name", "vlan").create()
schema.edgeLabel("linkTo").connection("site","site").add()

schema.vertexLabel("site").index("search").search().by("name").by("vlan").asText().add()
schema.vertexLabel("site").index("siteBySiteId").materialized().by("name").add()
schema.vertexLabel("site").index("toLink").outE("linkTo").by("vlan").add()
schema.vertexLabel("site").index("fromLink").inE("linkTo").by("vlan").add()

AA = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'site', 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'AA', 'vlan', '3353', 'vlan', '3563', 'vlan', '2467')
BB = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'site', 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'BB', 'vlan', '3353', 'vlan', '3563')
CC = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'site', 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'CC', 'vlan', '2467')
DD = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'site', 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'CC', 'vlan', '3353', 'vlan', '3563', 'vlan', '2467')

AA.addEdge('linkTo', BB, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'AA-BB', 'vlan', '3353', 'vlan', '3563')
AA.addEdge('linkTo', CC, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'AA-CC', 'vlan', '2467')
BB.addEdge('linkTo', DD, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'BB-DD', 'vlan', '3353', 'vlan', '3563')
CC.addEdge('linkTo', DD, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'CC-DD', 'vlan', '2467')`enter code here

--------------------
g.V().
  has("site", "name", "AA").  
  emit().
  repeat(timeLimit(200).both("linkTo").        
   filter(bothE("linkTo").                   
     has("vlan",Search.tokenPrefix("3353"))). 
   simplePath()).                             
  has("name", "DD").                     
  path().unfold()
```

but no success :)

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of things going on here:

First in your creation script this line has the `name` property set to `CC` instead of `DD`

```
DD = graph.addVertex(T.label, 'site', 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'CC', 'vlan', '3353', 'vlan', '3563', 'vlan', '2467')
```

Second, In Gremlin you cannot add multiproperties ([described here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-properties)) to edges, they are only valid on vertices.  As such you will need to change your load script to add parallel edges, one for each `vlan` property like this:

```
AA.addEdge('linkTo', BB, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'AA-BB', 'vlan', '3353')
AA.addEdge('linkTo', BB, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'AA-BB', 'vlan', '3563')
AA.addEdge('linkTo', CC, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'AA-CC', 'vlan', '2467')
BB.addEdge('linkTo', DD, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'BB-DD', 'vlan', '3353')
BB.addEdge('linkTo', DD, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'BB-DD', 'vlan', '3563')
CC.addEdge('linkTo', DD, 'id', UUID.randomUUID(), 'name', 'CC-DD', 'vlan', '2467')
```

Since you didn't give much detail on what you were trying to get for an answer I inferred that you were looking for all paths from `AA` to `DD` where the `vlan` is `3353`.  This can be done is a couple of different ways.  If you create the parallel edges such as above you can accomplish this using this Gremlin traversal:

```
g.V().
  has("site", "name", "AA").
  repeat(
    timeLimit(200).
    bothE("linkTo").
    has("vlan","3353").
    otherV().
    simplePath()
  ).until(has("name", "DD")).
  path().by('name')
```

If you instead decide that you only want to store the `vlan` property on the vertices you can get that via Gremlin like this:

```
g.V().
  has("site", "name", "AA").
  repeat(
    timeLimit(200).
    both("linkTo").
    has("vlan","3353").
    simplePath()
  ).until(has("name", "DD")).
  path().by('name').dedup()
```

The downside of this is that the `path` will not contain the edges.  If you want the edge information in the `path` as well you can change the `both()` step to be a `bothE()/otherV()` pattern like this:

```
g.V().
  has("site", "name", "AA").
  repeat(
    timeLimit(200).
    bothE("linkTo").
    otherV().
    has("vlan","3353").
    simplePath()
  ).until(has("name", "DD")).
  path().by('name').dedup()
```